# Google Analytics Enhanced E-commerce Tracking/Analytics is not working via GTM

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

For my website I already have GA & GTM. Enhanced E-commerce is already enabled. As can see from below image.

[image]

I have tried below code as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || [];
      w[l].push(
          {'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'}
      );
      var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
      j.async = true;
      j.src =
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
      f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
  })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXX');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

  <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript>
  <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
          height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
</head>
<body>
  <script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];


dataLayer.push({
  "event": "addToCart",
  "ecommerce": {
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "add": {
      "products": [{
        "id": "57b9d",
        "name": "Kiosk T-Shirt",
        "price": "55.00",
        "brand": "Kiosk",
        "category": "T-Shirts",
        "variant": "red",
        "dimension1": "M",
        "quantity": 1
      }]
    }
  }
});

dataLayer.push({
   'event' : 'purchase',
   'transactionId': '1234',
   'transactionAffiliation': 'Acme Clothing',
   'transactionTotal': 38.26,
   'transactionTax': 1.29,
   'transactionShipping': 5,
   'transactionProducts': [{
       'sku': 'DD44',
       'name': 'T-Shirt',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'price': 11.99,
       'quantity': 1
   },{
       'sku': 'AA1243544',
       'name': 'Hat',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'price': 9.99,
       'quantity': 2
   }]
});




ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-4');
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('set', 'currencyCode', 'SGD');
ga('ec:addProduct', {
  'id': 'P12345',
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt - with UA 4',
  'category': 'Apparel',
  'brand': 'Google',
  'variant': 'black',
  'price': '29.20',
  'quantity': 1
});

// Transaction level information is provided via an actionFieldObject.
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
  'id': 'T12345',
  'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online - with UA 4',
  'revenue': '37.39',
  'tax': '2.85',
  'shipping': '5.34',
  'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'    // User added a coupon at checkout.
});

ga('send', 'pageview');     // Send transaction data with initial pageview.

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have followed https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/enhanced-ecommerce/

[image]

Although doing above things it is still not showing any result.

[image]

I want to track two things initially.

1. Product added to cart
2. Order purchase

Any help on above one greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**[UPDATE]**

I have followed below tutorial as well.

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgLGWvhOyHU
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G5wvjC1rHo
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpUtb_Grl2A **[I have done GTM settings like this]**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measure_purchases -> I tried this already

So my latest test code is now

```
<script>
var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
  'event' : 'transaction',
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'T12345',                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
        'affiliation': 'Online Store',
        'revenue': '35.43',                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
        'tax':'4.90',
        'shipping': '5.99',
        'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
      },
      'products': [{                            // List of productFieldObjects.
        'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',     // Name or ID is required.
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '15.25',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Gray',
        'quantity': 1,
        'coupon': ''                            // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
       },
       {
        'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
        'id': '67890',
        'price': '33.75',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Black',
        'quantity': 1
       }]
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

[image]

**1st issue it is not showing any event over here.**

[image]

**[LATEST UPDATE]**

[image]

I am able to get events now, but in E-commerce overview still it's blank

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

- **You have duplicate tracking** even though right now nothing seems to be working, when things do, you'll end up with duplicate events. You either want to use GTM `dataLayer.push` OR the native `ga` calls, but you don't want to track purchases with both. **My advise is to migrate everything to GTM** since it gives you more control (ie you can extend/edit your analytics without having to change your source code each time).
- **The GTM purchase syntax is wrong**: see https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases for syntax example, **although make sure you add the "event" key so you can setup GTM triggers**.
- **You're not showing us whether GTM tags are firing**: by default GTM will do nothing with your data. For data to be sent to GA you need to configure triggers and tags.
- **Use the Chrome GA debugger plugin**: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en. After install, click on the extension icon to enable it and open up the browser console:

  - if you don't see debug, it means no GA tracking calls (whether native or via GTM) are firing
  - when they are, you will see debug info, including potential errors with explanations as to why data is not being sent
  - if you see the data being sent to GA properly but not appear there it's most likely a GA config error such as filters or sometimes sending data to the wrong property
- **Keep in mind about analytics/cookie blockers** you may have installed which prevent tracking.

Comment: Hi @Max, Thanks for answer. Let me go through it. Yes our everything is already migrated to GTM. So for analytics we are not using GA (UA--XXX-XX) code. We are using GTM-XXXXX. But for testing purpose I have added those

Comment: Hi @Max, I tried all things as you mentioned & I also put update in question as well. It will be good if you can give some guidance on this. Thanks